# Angular Material How to disable an svg icon

Tags: css, svg, angular-material

Similar to the classic bootstrap disabled state -

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled>Primary button</button>`

I'd like to simulate a `disabled` state on an `Angular Materials` svg icon using `cursor: not-allowed` css. But I want to disable the click event.

```css
.toolbar-icon-disabled {
    fill: gray;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
  <mat-icon svgIcon="historical-compare" [class.toolbar-icon-disabled]="true"></mat-icon>
```

Problem here is that I CANNOT use both `not-allowed` and `pointer-events: none`, as they appear to be mutually exclusive.

ex/ Here you can see that my left-most icon appears disabled, as the `fill` color is gray; however, it's still clickable if I add `cursor: not-allowed`.

[image: left icon disabled]

I couldn't copy/paste the not-allowed circle from my screen, but here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested work around:
1) Put the mat-icon in another anchor tag and add curson not allowed to that anchor.
HTML:

```
<a [class.linkDisabled]="true"><mat-icon svgIcon="historical-compare" [class.toolbar-icon-disabled]="true"></mat-icon></a>
```

CSS:

```
.toolbar-icon-disabled {pointer-events: none;}
.linkDisabled {cursor: not-allowed;}
```

2) keep the 'cursor: not-allowed;' in the css and i am assuming that there will be an event listener on the icon to do some action. Go into that method, check for the disabled condition and return if true. For example:

html:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="historical-compare" [class.toolbar-icon-disabled]="flgDisabled" (click)="onClick()"></mat-icon>
```

method:

```
  onClick() {
    if(this.flgDisabled) {
      return
    }
    console.log('called');
  }
```

Comment: We have the click event covered; and yes, I thought the same thing in terms of just returning if disabled. But what I was looking for seems to be what you suggested. I also thought of wrapping the mat-icon within the `<a>` tag, but I never thought of styling it separately. That was a good idea. I'm testing it now...